# How to remove element from json data column

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgres. I have table acqdata with column name jsondata  defined as type text and has the below value

```
{
  "a": [
    "valueofa"
  ],
  "countryCode": "USA",
  "b": {
    "bvalue": true,
    "c": [
      "value1",
      "value2"
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to update the jsondata column to remove the object b which is

```
"b": {
        "bvalue": true,
        "c": [
          "value1",
          "value2"
        ]
      }
```

I tried few options of other threads nothing worked may be because the column is defined as text.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So cast it to jsonb, apply the already known options, then cast it back to text.  Better yet, change the column type.

Comment: thanks jsondata::jsonb #- '{b}' => this one worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use operator `-` in jsonb for remove element

```sql
select '{
  "a": [
    "valueofa"
  ],
  "countryCode": "USA",
  "b": {
    "bvalue": true,
    "c": [
      "value1",
      "value2"
    ]
  }
}' :: jsonb - 'b'
```